# Using mod rewrite to redirect, using query string value with characters replaced

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have old URLs like this:

```
http://www.foo.org/cgi-bin/search.cgi?Blog=14&tag=my%20long%20tag%20name&limit=100
```

which I want to redirect to another server's page like:

```
http://www.bar.org/tag/my-long-tag-name/
```

On foo.org I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Blog=14&tag=([^&]*)&.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/search.cgi$ http://www.bar.org/tag/%1/?  [NC,R=301,L]
```

This redirects to the correct page on bar.org, where I need to replace the `%20`s with hyphens. However, it changes every `%20` to `%2520`. I've tried adding the `NE` flag, but no change. **This is the thing I'm stuck with.**

Once there, this rule replaces `%20`s with hyphens:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/tag/([^\s]*)(?:\s)+(.*)/$ /blog/tag/$1-$2/ [R=301,L]
```

(Bonus points... some of those original `tag` values also have `%28` and `%29` in them, which ultimately I'd like to delete. So a tag of `bob%20and%20%28thelma%29` becomes `bob-and-thelma`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in site root .htaccess of `www.foo.org`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# temporary rewrite to /tag/tag-name
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Blog=14&tag=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/search\.cgi$ /tag/%1? [L]

# redirect to http://www.bar.org if there is no special char in URI
RewriteRule ^tag/[^\x20\x28\x29]+$ http://www.bar.org/$0 [NC,L,NE,R=301]

# if special char is in the end then simple remove it
RewriteRule ^(tag)/([^\x20\x28\x29]*)[\x20\x28\x29]+$ $1/$2 [NC,N,DPI]

# otherwise replace special char by a hyphen    
RewriteRule ^(tag)/([^\x20\x28\x29]*)[\x20\x28\x29]+(.+)$ $1/$2-$3 [NC,N,DPI]
```

Comment: anubhava that's amazing! Thank you so much! I just about understand how that works but would never have got there. One thing - in line 4 there should be a `/` before `tag/%1?`. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I had `RewriteBase /` in my testing, that's why I didn't need `/` before `tag` but modified now